# Add custom headers and retrieve custom header using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am currently using Microsoft Graph API to retrieve my email, send new email and answer to an email.

I use Code Grant authorization to identify my user and access its information.

**PROBLEM**

This application let the user send email to our customers that have unpaid invoice. But the application uses `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` (with `$search` set to the customer email) to retrieve every mail that involves the customer, so the user can trace every conversation made by other employees.

The problem is to be able to differentiate emails (sent from our app) from others mails (sent from Outlook app). We would like to use email headers, which are accepted by a large amount of mail servers, and with which we could filter the search result to inform the user which email comes from our app.

The desired outcome would be that for example, I could be able to call Microsoft Graph API like so :

1. `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` with OData Parameters : `$search="john.doe@gmail.com"` and `$select=subject,bodyPreviewreceivedDateTime,headers`
2. Then asuming the request has send back a `200` code the JSON output would be :

[image]

Notice the `X-MY-COMPANY-INVOICE`, which would be the ultimate goal for us to let the app be aware this was sent from our app and not from Outlook app.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to perform this using Microsoft Graph API? If not, does Microsoft plan to release this feature any soon?

**QUESTION 2**

I am opened to suggestion, is this the best way to do this or am I going right on the wall with this technique? If yes, what would be the best way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for [Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview). You can use these mechanisms to attach custom data to an element (messages, events, users, groups, etc.).

There are several types of extensions available with Microsoft Graph: [Extended Properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview), [Open Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/opentypeextension) or [Schema Extension](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension). Each has it's own set of constraints so it is worth reviewing each to determine which works best for your scenario and architecture. That said, based on your description, I suspect Schema Extensions may be the best fit here.

Comment: Thank you, I am playing on the Graph Explorer to see if it could fit our need. In fact, I was thinking, does this mecanism is understood only in Exchange protocol? What I mean is, if for example I send an email with a specific schema extension at a customer using Gmail, does this information is persistent and can be retrieved back when receiving the mail of the same customer answering my mail ? Or is this Exchange-specific?

Comment: They are stored within the mailbox so they won't go to the recipient. If you want to link responses, you can connect the dots using the `conversationId` property. You could also process incoming messages and if a response comes in using the `/delta` and add your extension data in the background.

Comment: Great, I came up with a solution where I will "notify" (e.g. a visible tag on the mail displayed in html to inform the user) the app user that this received email is part of a conversation that have started with an email sent from our app thanks to the combination of `singleValueExtendedProperties` custom property and some algorithm that will, for a conversation id that have been successfuly identifyied as sent from our app, find any other email that match the same conversation id and flag them also! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just found out they are [working on](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/internetmessageheader). I have used the extensions to create successfully a custom `x-my-company`, but I am not able to fetch it (this is the only property that is missing for this [beta endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/message)). Gonna use this solution, hopefuly they ship the `internetMessageHeaders` into the v1!