# Is it possible to update office 365 Email Headers using "schema extensions" with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: odata, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We are trying to convert from EWS into Microsoft Graph API , I saw that the basic `"schema extensions"` with api: GET -
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages

the response is:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "receivedDateTime": "datetime-value",
      "sentDateTime": "datetime-value",
      "hasAttachments": true,
      "subject": "subject-value",
      "body": {
        "contentType": "",
        "content": "content-value"
      },
      "bodyPreview": "bodyPreview-value"
    }
  ]
}
```

following the ask question:

[Add custom headers and retrieve custom header using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711529/add-custom-headers-and-retrieve-custom-header-using-microsoft-graph-api?rq=1)

I want to insert some headers like EWS protocol following the picture below:

[image]

P.S:

I saw it is possible in beta version:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/internetmessageheader.md

How can I do it exactly ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `internetMessageHeaders` property is read-only. You can't set arbitrary headers on an outgoing message directly via Graph.

With EWS, you had to set an extended property in the `InternetHeaders` property set. You could do the same thing via Graph using [singleValueLegacyExtendedProperties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty) with a little digging :).

First, we need the GUID for the `InternetHeaders` property set. From [MS-OXPROPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219487(v=exchg.80).aspx), that value is `00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046`. So following along with the instructions to [create a single-value extended property](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_post_singlevalueextendedproperties), we come up with a property id like:

```
String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name X-MY-COMPANY-INVOICE
```

Now I can modify the JSON payload I POST to the `/sendMail` endpoint to include this property with a value:

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "adelev@contoso.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
      {
        "id": "String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name X-MY-COMPANY-INVOICE",
        "value": "This is my value that I put here. Isn't it neat?"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply , but I need a property name "headers" with array [ ] of other {K,V} properties...in your answer it is only 1 prop' name X-MY-COMAPNY... am I right ?

Comment: Sure. But it's an array so you can add more there.

Comment: The solution doesn't work. The existing email source is not updated with new headers and this http request "graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[userid]/messages/[resourceid]?$select=internetMessageHeaders" doesn't return new header.